# How can I ask my guests to eat vegan when I host them?

Tags: veganism, outreach, living-with-omnivores

When I host an event or have guests over to my home, how can I insist that they do not bring animal products to consume at the event? In particular, I am interested in how to handle ethical opposition to such products without appearing ungrateful for what they might bring, or forcing my views on them.

Comment: As long as your are upfront about your expectations when offering to host the event and inviting people over, I would say it's fair to forbid animal products. It is your house, after all. If they have a problem with it, they can always choose not to attend.

Comment: I feel like this has the same problem as your other question in that we'll just be giving our personal opinion. It would be better I think to ask how you can get away with it, than whether it's acceptable.

Comment: Yes, I recognize that the same criticisms apply here. I've just [asked](http://meta.vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/135/are-questions-relating-to-dealing-with-specific-social-situations-on-topic) about these types of questions on meta.vegetarianism and will make an effort to improve them.

Comment: Do you need to? If you're not eating them, what's the problem?  I don't have a problem with guests bringing their own non-vegan food to consume or even getting takeaway.  My only restriction is that I don't want them to cook their own food with my utensils, and people get that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The host generally makes the rules for an event, so a condition like that is entirely appropriate.  If they have dietary/medical needs that they feel cannot be met by vegan means, you might want to ask them to check with you

The way you explain the expectation is going to be entirely culture-dependent.  One possibility is including verbiage along the lines of "Guests are encouraged to bring a dish to pass, but please limit yourself to vegan options."

Be warned, though, that with a restriction like this, some people may be turned off, or just decide it's less trouble to skip bringing a contribution.  It might be less polarizing to allow non-vegan dishes, but encourage guests to label their dishes if they contain non-vegan or potential allergens "due to dietary restrictions on the part of the host and/or other guests".

Comment: You should also remind guests what you mean by vegan. For example, people will normally not think about the fact that most wine and beer are not vegan. Also be clear if you consider honey to be vegan or not. If you don't specify these sorts of things, be grateful if people attempted to bring something vegan but made a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is. You are the host and you are offering them a place at your table. Unless there is a medical issue preventing someone to eat what you plan to cook (allergies, perhaps?) it would actually be inappropriate for them to bring their own food. I would say your best shot is to notify them about your intentions beforehand and see what they have to say about it. That way they can tell you their objections and you can judge whether they are serious enough for you to consider.

If someone asks you to explain your expectations, simply ask them whether they would require the host at an omnivore event to tailor their menu according to them, even against his beliefs (eg. demanding from muslim host to serve pork).

Comment: Got it in one..

Answer (score 3):

An example I usually call for when faced with this situation is responding "If you would invite people from a place where they eat dog and cat as much as they eat pork, would you serve dog and cat, or would you restrict your food options to those that you find appropriate yourself?". That usually does the trick. People who eat meat, invariably also eat non-meat foods. If nothing else, they will eat fries. But as others suggested, let your guests know before hand so they can grab a bite on the way to your place (as we all have done so often!).

Answer (score 2):

As with the other comments and answers, it is your house, your party, basically your rules!  However that comes across as a bit harsh when put like that.  Most reasonable people will not have a problem with your requirements - in fact it is a perfect opportunity to educate them.  Meat eaters often scoff at vegetarians, and vegans - mainly through ignorance of the 'product' itself.  If you serve a great tasting, interesting and nutritious meal then, maybe, just maybe you have converted someone.  If nothing else you may have broadened their horizons.  Perhaps say something like 'Hey guys, I know you are not vegetarian, but please allow me to surpise you - tonight is a meat free zone!'  If someone is not willing to stick by your rules, then do you really want them at your party?

Comment: Sometimes you might not be able to chose your guests though?

Comment: Ah rats - now that is a problem!  However I think that explaining nicely but firmly beforehand is maybe the answer then.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think you should force your guests to conform to your world view.

Every person is different and by insisting that they all be like you in your presence is intolerant and preachy. And the very thing you are seeking is for people to be tolerant of you and your personal choices.

Ideally your personal choices would make you stand out as different and people would ask you about it because they are curious why. Those are the best times to talk on an open and even field.

I didn't become a vegetarian because someone told me about an ethical issue I was in violation of, instead I quit associating with "those" people.

This is an ethical issue, and if you were to reverse the role and be honest you would see how rediculous it would be for you to be asked to eat meat at someone's wing night.

I have a beef farmer father in law and my mother and brothers think that it's impossible to have a meal without a quarter plate of meat.

Comment: Point completely missed.  OP is not asking guests to 'conform to their world view', merely to have respect when they are in OP's house as a guest.  Based on your logic, you would keep your shoes on when entering a Japanese house, not put on or remove head covering in a religious situation and bring alcohol to an event hosted by a reformed alcoholic who asked you not to.

Comment: Well no considering my point was made from the stance of a host not a guest. I consider hospitality to be an act of welcoming, not division.

Comment: So if the host were a recovering alcoholic who preferred there to be no alcohol around, are you seriously suggesting it is not OK to ask people to not bring alcohol?

Comment: Alcoholism is a disease not a preference, you can't compare the two.

Comment: A better analogy might be asking guests to not bring pork into my kosher home.

Comment: I mean you can, what I'm saying is that doing so is legalistic and it alienates people and you need to decide to what end do you wish to do so.  For myself, I am willing to endure things I personally disagree with so that my home will be the one that people regard as a welcome space. We all know there aren't enough of those around.

Comment: My home is a welcome and loving space despite me asking people to not bring meat. At least i can count on my visitors to respect my choices.

Comment: @4LPH4NUM3R1C Sorry for joining this discussion so late , but I thought I had to make this comment . 'Alcoholism is a disease not a preference, you can't compare the two.' I do not agree with this. There are people out there who considers being veg*n not simply as a 'preference' but as a moral duty.